# google universal analytics using my own variables

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I would like to use my own variabls in google universal analytics. all the vallues are in spans and all the names are correct.

For some reason google analytics isn't seeing my variables and is just sending the data to analytics according to the names of my variables. (so if i call my variable price it sends the word price to analytics.

Is there a special way to call to javascript variables in google analytics or am i doing something wrong here?

I also tried multiple qoute's, brackets etc but none of them seem to be working.
also the variable prijs was some testing i did with another way of getting the field data from a span but doesn't give me any good results either.

Code:

```
            /*Ecommerce google analytics*/
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-[mycode]', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

        var ordernummer = document.getElementById("ordernummer").innerHtml;
        var totaalprijs = document.getElementById("totaalprijs").innerHtml;
        var verzendkost = document.getElementById("verzendkost").innerHtml;
        var artikelnr = document.getElementById("artikelnr").innerHtml;
        var naam = document.getElementById("naam").innerHtml;
        var prijs = parseFloat(regexResult);
        var aantal = document.getElementById("aantal").innerHtml;

        ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

        ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {

        'id':  ordernummer ,                                                    
        'affiliation': 'Skatestore.com',                                        
        'revenue': (totaalprijs) ,                                                  
        'shipping': (verzendkost) ,                                                 
        'tax': '' });                                                           

        ga('ecommerce:addItem', {

        'id': (ordernummer) ,                                                   
        'sku': (artikelnr) ,                                                    
        'name': (naam)                                                          
        'category': '',                                                         
        'price': (prijs) ,                                                          
        'quantity': (aantal) });                                                

        ga('ecommerce:send');
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be .innerHTML? Javascript is case sensitive, so there is no such field as innerHtml in an object.

Comment: Yes, you are right, should be uppercase. I tried it but it still didn't work.

Comment: Do those elements exist yet on the page when you try to get them? Typically the GA snippet should be in the <head> tags of your page, so when I see trying to DOM scrape for them right below the snippet, then I would think that those elements haven't been created yet.

Comment: My conclusion was that it was better to put it in the lower en of the body. the pagfe consist of 2 file's. A skin and the page itself. (skin containign some javascript and the genral design and the other page containign all the date. Upon entering the page the 2 files should become 1 page containing both files.